# VisualForce calls a getter method only once

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I wish for a getter method to return a different value when it's called multiple times. Similar to the one below:

```java
Iterator<String> itr = new List<String>{'one','two','three','four','five'}.iterator();

public String getValue(){
    if(itr.hasNext())
        return itr.next();
    else
        return 'No more values';
}
```

In [visualforce](/questions/tagged/visualforce), I use it as such:

```
<!-- getNumber() called 5 times in a single visualforce page, NOT in a loop -->
{!value}
{!value}
{!value}
{!value}
{!value}
{!value}
```

and the output is:

```
one one one one one one
```

Is there any way to have it print out like:

```
one two three four five No more values
```

It seems that the [visualforce](/questions/tagged/visualforce) parser calls getValue() only once and caches the value for the remainder of the page.

Making the iterator static or

Comment: Visualforce docs explicitly tell us to "Do not use side-effects in your getters or setters!" and to not count on the amount or order in which getters & setters are called. Why would you want to make such abomination? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller_lifecycle_example.htm

Comment: Mostly because <apex:include pageName="{!someValue}"/> does not work in an <apex:repeat ...>

I have a very finite list of pages I wish to include (only 10) but the order may shift.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use getters with side effects... I'm not surprised they're actually caching the values and no amount of `transient` can save you.

You can pull that off by exposing `List<String> values {get;private set;}` and then in Visualforce calling `{!values[3]}` or even `{!values[i]}` (where `i` can be an Integer variable from controller or even `<apex:variable>` although that's quite hardcore... Just sort your array of strings/page names in controller and display them in "fixed order" using the index on the VF side?

(The array syntax is quite powerful by the way, if you have `String fieldName = 'AccountNumber';`, you can have runtime binding with `{!acc[fieldName]}` in VF)

Another option would be to explore Dynamic Visualforce components? It seems you can't use them with `<apex:include>` though. But I know I had no problems including custom components in the past inside a repeat if that's of any help...